# Show the intention/quickfix window faster in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

In IntelliJ IDEA, an intentions/quickfix popup (with lightbulb icon) will appear when you hover the mouse over applicable lines of code for a second or so (or immediately if you press ALT-Enter). I have most popups like code completion set to display in 50 ms, so waiting a full second for the Quickfix window is maddening. Is there any way to decrease the delay?

I'm hoping for a delay setting, not the keyboard shortcut.

I've dug through the settings in IntelliJ and done plenty of web searches and can't find an answer to this.